# Best method to refresh display in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, refresh

I have a simple OpenGl scene with objects, and a function called by a timer every 1/30 secs to move objects in the scene.
What's the best method to tell OpenGl to refresh the screen ?
I am not using double buffering.

Answer (score 6):

You should definitely use double buffering (also for performance reasons). The canonical way to refresh a scene in OpenGL is to redraw the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks. Should I use the setNeedsDisplay method or rather the lockFocus method to instruct OpenGl to refresh ? Because if I don't use these methods and directly start the refresh function, the view doesn't redraw...

Comment: @Laurent Crivello: You don't instruct OpenGL to refresh. OpenGL just provides the drawing commands. All the other things are part of the operating system (which you didn't specify BTW, but I guess it's iOS). I'm not an iOS expert, but reading the documentation I'd say setNeedsDisplay is well suited.

Comment: I am actually developping for Mac on Xcode. Why I have issues with setNeedsDisplay, is that my function is executed every 1/30 of sec and it does a setNeedsDisplay at its end. However it happens that the function is executed up to 10 times before the drawRect is indeed executed. Is that normal ?

Comment: @Laurent Crivello: As I understand it setNeedDisplay just sets some flag, indicating the main event loop to issue a redraw. Calling setNeedDisplay multiple times thus has no real effect.

Comment: Thanks but my point is that redraw action is only executed "long" after the setNeedsDisplay has been set. In some cases after 1/3 of secs, when I would expect it right after. I however tried with the lockFocus / drawRect / unlockFocus combination and it seems to work better.